# Jquery form validation custom error placement in <div> container

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate my form fields.

The script is like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $.validator.addMethod(
    "mydate",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\-\d\d?\-\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy"
    );
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
  rules: {
            User: {
    required: true,
                remote: {
        url: "user.php",
        type: "post",
          },
   },
   "RID[]": {
    required: true,
                remote: {
        url: "resource.php",
        type: "post",
          },
   },
            Date: {
    required: true,
                mydate : true
            },
  },
  messages: {
   User: "Specify Active User",
   "RID[]": "Specify Available Resource",
            Date: "Specify Date"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
  },
  success: function(label) {
   label.html("OK").addClass("checked");
  }
 });
```

which validates one of my form field

```
<tr>
<td style="width: 70px" class="style22" valign="top">Resource ID</td>
<td id="resource" style="width: 267px;">
<input id="resource" name="RID[]" type="text" value="" style="width: 232px" /></td>
<td class="style21" style="width: 160px" valign="top">
<img id="addScnt" alt="[+]" src="+.gif"/>
</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
```

But I want to place error for "RID[]" in a specific div `<div id="errorcontainer2">`.

How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it using custom error placement in a specific div `<div id="errorbox">`

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element){
    if(element.attr("name") == "RID[]"){
        error.appendTo($('#errorbox'));
    }else{
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a div with an id.
2. use a selector to grab your error div.
3. use the [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function to add your error HTML to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following structure and logic in `errorPlacement` option of validator to code:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element){
    if("RID[]" == element.attr("name")){
        // Place error for RID[] as you want
    }else{
        // Place errors normally
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i add `<div id="errorcontainer2">` in ur syntax??